# Значение пословицы "Не спеши, коза, все волки твои будут"

Tags: семантика, пословицы

О чём это? Каково **дословное значение** фразы (для козы) и **в чём мораль** этой пословицы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд,  что-то подобное пословице: "Тише едешь - дальше будешь". В современной интерпретации можно представить так (обращаясь к женщине за рулём):

"Не спеши, а то все гаишники твои будут!"

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и интересный пример.

Answer (score 1):

**Я немного дополню ответ.**

Мне кажется, что в полном варианте эта фраза может звучать так: "Не спеши, коза, в лес, не то все волки твои будут”.  И речь здесь идет **о риске вообще.** То есть не спеши участвовать в рискованных делах, которые олицетворяет лес, полный волков.

Надо сказать, что в Интернете встречаются разные толкования этой пословицы, причем, как мне кажется, **не очень верные.**